# How to create a function with input/output in r?

Tags: r, function, input, output

I'm thinking in a function that the user enters with an input, as follows:

```
cat("check if the directory is the same of the file")
input <- readline(prompt="Enter with file name in form >file.txt<: ")
output<-readline(prompt="Enter with file output in form >file.dat<: ")
```

Then, after the user enter with a .txt file name is evaluated the vector "sum", by the way:

```
column <- read.table(input, header=F)
sum = column * 2
```

Finally, the txt file output is generated:

```
write.table(sum, file=output, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

It works but i don't know how transform all of this in a function.

Comment: I can see nothing in this that prepending `myfunc <- function() {` and appending `}` will not transform this code into a function.

Comment: @r2evans, you have reason. Only that works, thanks!